# How to know which opto-coupler is suitable for high current application?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, consumer-electronics, microelectronics

I would like a suitable opto-coupler to use as isolation from a 12V and around 30A current and another for 5V and around 30A. Are there any good opto-couplers for those ratings?

Comment: Start with the spec sheet.

Comment: Search for solid state relays. Some of them can well contain an opto-coupler as the input stage. Your low voltage DC probably cannot stand the voltage drop (say 1V) in a thyristor or triac, so search for types which have spec for low enough output voltage drop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optocouplers are made for milliamperes. You expect a switching circuit where a high current transistor or mosfet is controlled through an optocoupler or other isolation providing part.

Such circuits are sold as ready to use components. One for your purposes could have name DC solid state relay with low output voltage drop.

The unfortunate fact is that your low DC voltage 5 or 12 volts probably cannot stand much voltage drop. The common equivalent series resistance of low cost mosfets is say 60 milliohms which means 1,8 volt drop at 30A. Fortunately there also exists for low voltage and high current applications special low drop types which have say 2 milliohms equivalent series resistance. An example: Infineon IPD100N04S402ATMA1

That will drop at 30A only 60 millivolts, which can be acceptable (a guess only).

Let's assume you succeed to buy one. You need still the control electronics which generates to the mosfet gate-source voltage = +10 volts for on state and 0V for off state and makes the transition between the states as quickly as your application needs.

For sparse switching on and off the control circuit can be simple - only check that during the transition (=in the half conductive period) the mosfet will not get too hot. I guess you need an electronics designer to make the calculations. If your application is controlling something with PWM and the load is something more complex than a constant resistance the job needs an experienced designer, a casual hobbyist or a beginner simply cannot make it right.

Getting +10V to control the mosfet needs a separate DC source or a DC/DC converter - There's no other way to control the mosfet than generate somehow the needed gate-source voltage; in this case it's +10V for ON-state. Special care is needed to prevent any switching attempts before the control circuit is surely stabilized when the system is taken into use by connecting ON the operating voltages.

For these reasons I suggest to get a ready to use solid state relay. Unfortunately I do not know the market nor your application well enough to suggest any certain type.